# How to implement edge's on hover event on a canvas for arbor.js JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, html5-canvas, arbor.js

I'm trying to hack [arbor.js](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor) so I can perform on edges hover event and then display any information from it.

[image]

So let's say I can move over any edge and detect which edge's been hovered.

This is the drawing edges part of the **[rendering code](https://raw.github.com/samizdatco/arbor/master/demos/halfviz/src/renderer.js)**:

```
particleSystem.eachEdge(function(edge, pt1, pt2){
  // edge: {source:Node, target:Node, length:#, data:{}}
  // pt1:  {x:#, y:#}  source position in screen coords
  // pt2:  {x:#, y:#}  target position in screen coords


  // find the start point
  var tail = intersect_line_box(pt1, pt2, nodeBoxes[edge.source.name])
  var head = intersect_line_box(tail, pt2, nodeBoxes[edge.target.name])

  ctx.save() 

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.lineWidth = (!isNaN(weight)) ? parseFloat(weight) : 1
  ctx.strokeStyle = (color) ? color : "#cccccc"
  ctx.fillStyle = null

  //We save edge's line data, "Diego"
  var slope = ((head.y)-(tail.y))/((head.x)-(tail.x))
  a.push({x1:tail.x, y1:tail.y, x2:head.x, y2:head.y, m:slope})

  ctx.moveTo(tail.x, tail.y)
  ctx.lineTo(head.x, head.y)
  ctx.stroke()

  // Why pushing here makes x2 and y2 undefined?, "Diego"
  ctx.restore()
})
```

This is the refered function:

```
var intersect_line_box = function(p1, p2, boxTuple)
{
  var p3 = {x:boxTuple[0], y:boxTuple[1]},
      w = boxTuple[2],
      h = boxTuple[3]

  var tl = {x: p3.x, y: p3.y};
  var tr = {x: p3.x + w, y: p3.y};
  var bl = {x: p3.x, y: p3.y + h};
  var br = {x: p3.x + w, y: p3.y + h};

  return intersect_line_line(p1, p2, tl, tr) ||
        intersect_line_line(p1, p2, tr, br) ||
        intersect_line_line(p1, p2, br, bl) ||
        intersect_line_line(p1, p2, bl, tl) ||
        false
}
```

## I thought about two approaches:

> **First approach**

First one is adding a 'hover' anonymous function inside **`var handler = {...}`**. So when **`$(canvas).mousemove(handler.hover)`**  all would be managed by hover's function. I thought capturing the mouse's position and comparing it with the previous edges line coordinates.

I have a variable like:

`var a = []`

And then, before drawing again I clear out saved edges:

`a=[]`

And save the to be drawed edges:

```
var slope = ((head.y)-(tail.y))/((head.x)-(tail.x))
a.push({x1:tail.x, y1:tail.y, x2:head.x, y2:head.y, m:slope})
```

So, hover's event function is:

```
      hover: function(e) {
        var pos = $(canvas).offset();
        var x = e.pageX-pos.left
        var y = e.pageY-pos.top
        _mouseP = arbor.Point(e.pageX-pos.left, e.pageY-pos.top)


        for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
            if ( (_mouseP.x-a[i].x1)) == (a[i].m* (_mouseP.y-a[i].y1)) )
                console.log("This is an edge)
      },
```

> **Second approach**

What about going for jQuery? So something like:

`$("anyDrawedOnCanvasStuff").hover(function(){}`

would trigger events automatically. However I don't think this as possible, is it?

I quite completed first approach, but something weird is happening with the saved points in `a` array, they're all double and obtained mouse points happened to be integer. And also, they don't even get close to complete the formula's logic.

Comment: Hi Diego, do you have a jsfiddle or something? it's hard to find the mistake by looking only.

Comment: why don't you put the render.js and arbor.js tags into your question? you won't get any answer with an html or hover tag because the professionals won't be able to see your question amigo